# Binary logistic regression in R - assistance with determining odds of a predictor at different levels

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

I have performed a binary logistic regression in R with whether or not a sportsperson was re-contracted or not as the DV. My final model is as follows;

```
Model1.0<-glm(Recontracted ~ Debut.first.year + Grouped.by.fives + 
Draft.year + Maturity + Games.second.season.DC + Interstate.vic.team + 
Rising.star + Team.EOS.ladder.second.year.raw, family = binomial, data = 
mydata)
```

Draft year is a significant predictor in the model. I would now like to know what the probability of being re-contracted is for each draft year (1999-2012) but am unsure how to write the R code for this. For example, what is the probability of being re-contracted if you were drafted in 1999, 2000, 2001 etc (up to 2012).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the summary output of Model1.0. Please let me know if any further information in required.

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.4290   0.0967   0.2981   0.6764   1.5981  

Coefficients:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     -120.69457   46.78377  -2.580 0.009885 ** 
Debut.first.year                   0.67977    0.21772   3.122 0.001795 ** 
Grouped.by.fives                  -0.11849    0.02361  -5.019 5.21e-07 ***
Draft.year                         0.06109    0.02334   2.617 0.008863 ** 
Maturity                          -0.65844    0.40981  -1.607 0.108118    
Games.second.season.DC             1.87716    0.34011   5.519 3.40e-08 ***
Interstate.vic.team                0.47625    0.19390   2.456 0.014044 *  
Rising.star                        1.50635    0.44429   3.390 0.000698 ***
Team.EOS.ladder.second.year.raw   -0.04403    0.02062  -2.135 0.032728 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 905.68  on 937  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 704.90  on 929  degrees of freedom
AIC: 722.9

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

Comment: What you estimate by a logistic regression is $\text{log-odds}$ (so if you plug-in the reading for you $i$-th subject you will get the $\text{log-odds}$ of it). If you exponentiate it that number you get the $\text{odds}$ ratio and if you want to get proportions ($\approx$ probability) you need to use $\frac{\text{odds}}{1+\text{odds}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am familiar with the content of your comment however, what I am specifically looking for is the probability (or log odds or odds ratio - it doesn't really matter which one as I can use one to calculate the other) of being re-contracted in each draft year. At the moment, all I know is that draft year is a significant predictor. I need this question answered - what is the probability (or log odds) of being recontracted if you were drafted in 1999 vs 2000 vs 2001 etc up to 2012. Can this be done?

Comment: Every additional year later that the sportsperson is contracted later, the odds of being re-contracted increase with a factor $\exp(0.06109)=1.063$ or 6.3%.

Comment: Did you try the 'predict' function ?

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to reply. I have tried the predict function but I am unsure how to include all independent variables in this function as I have read that these will need to be kept at a constant or their mean. I have a combination of discrete and dummy coded variables - how are dummy coded variables kept at their mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is : $\displaystyle log\left(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1,i} + ... + \beta_px_{p,i}$
with $p_i = \mathbb{P}\left[y_i = 1 | x_{1,i},...,x_{p,i}\right]$
Thus, $p_i = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1,i} + ... + \beta_px_{p,i}}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1,i} + ... + \beta_px_{p,i}}}$

The probability $ p(1 | x_j = a)$ is $\frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_j \times a}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_j \times a}}$
e.g. with your data the probability of being re-contracted if you were drafted in 1999, all other things being equal, is $\frac{e^{-120.69457 + 0.06109  \times 1999}}{1 + e^{-120.69457 + 0.06109  \times 1999}} = 0.81$